# How to run multiple iterations of a script?

Tags: python, time

I want to measure the average run time (10 iterations) of a sort program in python, that sorts multiple inputs of randomly generated arrays of size n = (100, 150, 350, 500). I've have the following script but it keep returning a answer for the last input only.

```
#elements = list() 
times = list() 
for i in range(1, 11):   
    # generate some integers
    for n in (100, 150, 350, 500):
        a = randint(0, n, n)
        start = time.time() 
        Sortalgorithm(a) 
        end = time.time() 
        times.append(end-start) 
    #return size of readomly generated array and the mean time taken 
print (len(a), mean(times))
```

Comment: Have a look at timeit: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: "I've have the following script but it keep returning a answer for the last input only." Well, you explicitly ask it to take the arithmetic `mean` of the `times` values that you calculated, so I don't understand why you would expect otherwise.

Comment: What I want is to the the average of 10 iterations of the sort algorithm with and randomly generated array of n = 100, followed by the average of 10 iterations of the sort algorithm with and randomly generated array of n = 150......

Answer (score 2):

You will need to swap the order of your loop to fulfill what you want to do in the comments:

```
    #loop over the sizes of arrays first    
    for n in (100, 150, 350, 500): 
        times = list() #make the list for every size
        #repeat the test in for loop
        for i in range(1, 11):   
        # generate some integers    
            a = randint(0, n, n)
            start = time.time() 
            Sortalgorithm(a) 
            end = time.time() 
            times.append(end-start) 
        #return size of readomly generated array and the mean time taken, for each n 
        print (len(a), mean(times))
```

Comment: Thanks but I got as an output the last value for n and the time i.e.  500  0.00333

Comment: You would need to indent the print statement so that it is in the first for loop @Peadar08